# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting this:

**error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so'**

I tried putting this block of code in my gradle:

```
packagingOptions{
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so'
}
```

Then I get this error:

**error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libMyLibs.so'**

So I added this:

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libMyLibs.so'
}
```

And it built fine, but I can't install it on my device because I get this error:

**Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113**

Which means that it can't be installed on this type of architecture. So I don't think excluding armeabi-v7a is the answer.

Here's what I have in Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.citytelecoin.opencvfacetest"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "/home/liane/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary320')
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but for me this is only happening with android gradle 3.0+, 2.3 works fine.

Comment: For me this happened when including a jar with native libraries in an android library, my workaround for now is to extract the native libraries from the jar and to put them in jniLibs of the android library.

Comment: I AM also get same error ...plzz any one help us for this one

Comment: @Alex where is the android library located?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try it:

```
packagingOptions{
  pickFirst 'xxxxx.so'
}
```